# Unable to UpdateSettlementMethod with accountToPay (accountID) of String type

Tags: kotlin, blockchain, corda

I'm trying to create my own mock settlement rail using corda-settler but is facing an issue and I've been trying to resolve it for the past week, still I don't know what went wrong. I'm not sure if this issue is the same as the one raised by TAC911 [here](https://github.com/corda/corda-settler/issues/21).

This is the the command I'm running on the shell `start UpdateSettlementMethod linearId: 389b634d-2d4f-4f00-84e9-c903b0454e4d, settlementMethod: { accountToPay: dummyAccount001, settlementOracle: Oracle, _type: com.r3.corda.finance.dummy.types.DummySettlement }` and this is the errors:

```
Tue Jun 11 13:39:28 SGT 2019>>> start UpdateSettlementMethod linearId: 389b634d-2d4f-4f00-84e9-c903b0454e4d, settlementMethod: { accountToPay: dummyAccount001, settlementOracle: Oracle, _type: com.r3.corda.finance.dummy.types.DummySettlement }
No matching constructor found:
- [net.corda.core.contracts.UniqueIdentifier, com.r3.corda.finance.obligation.types.SettlementMethod]: Could not parse as a command: Could not resolve type id 'com.r3.corda.finance.dummy.types.DummySettlement' as a subtype of [simple type, class com.r3.corda.finance.obligation.types.SettlementMethod]: no such class found
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]
```

The followings are the classes I have created in my mock settlement module:
DummyPayment:

```
package com.r3.corda.finance.dummy.types

import com.r3.corda.finance.obligation.types.Money
import com.r3.corda.finance.obligation.types.Payment
import com.r3.corda.finance.obligation.types.PaymentReference
import com.r3.corda.finance.obligation.types.PaymentStatus
import net.corda.core.contracts.Amount

data class DummyPayment<T : Money>(
        override val paymentReference: PaymentReference,
        override val amount: Amount<T>,
        override var status: PaymentStatus = PaymentStatus.SENT
) : Payment<T> {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Amount: $amount, Dummy Reference: $paymentReference, Status: $status"
    }
}
```

DummySettlement:

```
package com.r3.corda.finance.dummy.types

import com.r3.corda.finance.obligation.types.OffLedgerPayment
import com.r3.corda.finance.dummy.flows.MakeDummyPayment
import net.corda.core.identity.Party

data class DummySettlement(
        override val accountToPay: String,
        override val settlementOracle: Party,
        override val paymentFlow: Class<MakeDummyPayment<*>> = MakeDummyPayment::class.java
) : OffLedgerPayment<MakeDummyPayment<*>> {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Pay to $accountToPay and use $settlementOracle as settlement Oracle."
    }
}
```

MakeDummyPayment:

```
package com.r3.corda.finance.dummy.flows

import co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Suspendable
import com.r3.corda.finance.dummy.types.DummyPayment
import com.r3.corda.finance.dummy.types.DummySettlement
import com.r3.corda.finance.obligation.client.flows.MakeOffLedgerPayment
import com.r3.corda.finance.obligation.states.Obligation
import com.r3.corda.finance.obligation.types.*
import net.corda.core.contracts.Amount
import net.corda.core.contracts.StateAndRef
import net.corda.core.flows.FlowException
import net.corda.core.utilities.ProgressTracker
import com.r3.corda.finance.dummy.types.*

class MakeDummyPayment<T : Money>(
        amount: Amount<T>,
        obligationStateAndRef: StateAndRef<Obligation<*>>,
        settlementMethod: OffLedgerPayment<*>,
        progressTracker: ProgressTracker
) : MakeOffLedgerPayment<T>(amount, obligationStateAndRef, settlementMethod, progressTracker) {

    @Suspendable
    override fun setup() {
    }

    override fun checkBalance(requiredAmount: Amount<*>) {
    }

    @Suspendable
    override fun makePayment(obligation: Obligation<*>, amount: Amount<T>): DummyPayment<T> {
        if (amount.token !is FiatCurrency)
            throw FlowException("Please only pay in FiatCurrency for now.")
        if (obligation.settlementMethod == null)
            throw FlowException("Please update the SettlementMethod to DummySettlement for now.")
        if (obligation.settlementMethod !is DummySettlement)
            throw FlowException("Please use only DummySettlement for now.")

        return DummyPayment((obligation.payments.size + 1).toString(), amount as Amount<FiatCurrency>, PaymentStatus.SENT) as DummyPayment<T>
    }
}
```

The command can be ran if it's being settled in XRP. I'm not sure if there is any relevance of the type of accountToPay (String type, in DummySettlement class) which might affect some other dependencies?

Any help or insights would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's the same issue as described here: https://github.com/corda/corda-settler/issues/21

The workaround is to create your own wrapper flow which takes strings for the parameters which cannot be deserialised then construct those objects in your flow and pass them into the corda settler flows.

Cheers

Comment: Hi Roger, may I ask if my understanding is correct, the workaround is either:
1. create a wrapper flow for UpdateSettlementMethod flow, which is able to take String for the accountToPay parameter type, then this flow will reconstruct my inputs (eg: accountToPay/settlementMethod etc) as a serializable object and then invoke a subFlow of the original UpdateSettlementMethod with the newly serialized object as input, or
2. I can create a wrapper for String class to serialize my String input, which will then be used as the accountToPay parameter type

Is this correct, or am I completely wrong?